# how to create a references with Bibtex?

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

Hello everybody I'm trying to cite a website using Bibtex but I can't show the URL in the articule that I'm working

this is my Bibtex cite:

```
@misc{Briggs_EarthSky_2023, title={What is a galaxy? all you need to know}, 
url={https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/definition-what-is-a-galaxy/}, 
journal={EarthSky}, 
author={Briggs, Andy and EarthSky}, 
year={2023}, 
month={Mar}}
```

The result was:

Briggs, A. and EarthSky (2023). What is a galaxy? all you need to know.

But I need to show the URL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.